# expressibility of formula $x \oplus y \oplus z$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it possible to express $\oplus_3(x, y, z) = x \oplus y \oplus z$ from f(x, y, z) = $xy \oplus xz \oplus z$ ? I expressed $xy$, $x \lor y$, $maj_3(x, y, z)[maj_3(x, y, z) = xy \oplus xz \oplus yz]$, and $x \oplus y \oplus z \oplus xy \oplus xz \oplus yz \oplus xyz$, but I can't find a way to express $x \oplus y \oplus z$.