# How to prove that $f(x) = x ? y : z$ is basis of $\mathcal{P}$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

$\mathcal{P}$ is the class of preserving 0 and 1. I expressed $x \lor y$ like $f(x, x, y)$ and $x \land y$ like $f(x, y, x)$. I also expressed $maj_3(x, y, z) = xz \oplus xy \oplus zy$ and $x \oplus y \oplus z \oplus xy \oplus xz \oplus yz \oplus xyz$. To finish the proof I need $\oplus_3(x, y, z) = x \oplus y \oplus z$, so I would be able to express all Zhegalkins polynomial with even quantity of terms and without 1, which makes exactly $\mathcal{P}$, but I can't find a way to express $\oplus_3(x, y, z)$.

Comment: How is $x\oplus y $ defined?

Comment: @JohnWatson, what exactly do you mean? $x \oplus y$ is xor

Comment: Yes, but this notation is not universal : it's good you recall it.

Comment: @JeanMarie, sorry for latency, yes, it is the same.

Comment: You already asked this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546250/expressibility-of-formula-x-oplus-y-oplus-z?rq=1. Please edit the previous question if you wish to improve it and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a cube out of the values of $f(x, y, z)$:

[image: Xor Cube]

where the values at the corners of the cube is $f(x, y, z)$, then you can see the back bottom has the $0$/$1$ value swapped.  So $f(x, 0, 1) = \lnot x$.  Since you can construct $\lnot$ and $\land$, the function is combinatorially complete.

Comment: Yes, it is, but we don't have nor 1, neither 0. $f(x, y, z)$ is preserving 0 and 1, so we can't express 1 and 0